# Residuals and AIC comparison

Tags: data-transformation, residuals, aic, logarithm

When I run my simple plant model, 
Length ~ Age + Location
I get a very strong increase of fitted residuals, almost like a perfect cone. When trying a logarithmic transformation (log(Length) ~ Age + Location) the residuals even out nicely. However, the AIC increases considerably (from 1200 to 3700). So my questions are these: which of these methods take precedence? Is my comparison of AIC:S ok in this case?*

Sincerely
/Stina

Answer (score 2):

AIC takes precedence. The fitted residuals are sensitive to the choice of units and range of the dependent variable. By considering log(Y) you did not make just residuals smaller. You made everything smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much! (Sorry for the late reply, family has been sick)